# type object 'Notification' has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django

I get this error from my views.py:

> type object 'Notification' has no attribute 'object'

and my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from notification.models import Notification

def show_notification(request, notification_id):
    n = Notification.object.get(id=notification_id)

    return render_to_response('notification.html', {'notification':n})
def delete_notification(request, notification_id):
    n = Notification.object.get(id=notification_id)
    n.viewed = True
    n.save()
```

and also my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Notification(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    message = models.TextField()
    viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)


def create_welcome_message(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        noti=Notification.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'],
                                    title="Welcome Message",
                                    message="Thank you for singing up!")


post_save.connect(create_welcome_message, sender=User)
```

I've been missing for a long time. using this language. Then help me with this error.

Comment: `object` --> `objects`

Comment: Thank you a lot bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get notification by using `Notification.object.get(id=notification.id)`.

Replace `object` with `objects` in order to query notifications.

for an instance, `Notification.objects.get(id=notification.id)`